# Fixed font-size from an array - D3 Jason Davies Example

Tags: arrays, d3.js, cloud, font-size

This Code below is an WordCloud example of Jason Davies.
I want insert an array with fixed font-size and integrate it randomly.

e.g.:

```
fontSize = [20,35,50,60,83,90];
```

I want it fix, as above (not with range[x,x]) like this:

```
var fontSize = d3.scale.log().range([20, 90]);
```

Has someone an idea how I can implement it.

Sorry, maybe it's a stupid question, am unfortunately still a beginner.

```
<script>
  var fill = d3.scale.category20();

  d3.layout.cloud().size([800, 800])
      .words([
        "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
        "than", "this"].map(function(d) {
        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
      }))
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();

  function draw(words) {
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 800)
        .attr("height", 800)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(400,400)")
      .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
      .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
  }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Be more attentive with your tags.  The "fix" tag is for FIX financial protocol, not for you wanting to fix something.

Comment: ups, sorry. I really wanted only just fix my problem. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do to is to fix those sizes for the words you want instead of generating them randomly. You can append them to the array with random sizes:

```
var words = ["Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
    "than", "this"].map(function(d) {
        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
    };
words.push({text: "foo", size: 20});
words.push(...);
```

The rest of the code shouldn't need any modifications at all. The code you've posted does not use any scales, so the font sizes that you generate and specify are the font sizes it will actually use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I would like to do it dynamically later.
Like this:

`.fontSize(function(d) { return Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1); })`

instead of this:

`.fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })`

In this way I would have a lot of "pushs" to do.
(For example, I had 100 or more words)

Comment: You can certainly write a loop to add the new elements to the array, or even append one array to another. If you want to set the font size randomly later, then you could introduce a flag that tells you whether to generate a random size or take the given one.

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can do that.